# Finding aggregate id based on dependency

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

i have a quite messy question since i'm not sure if this is more of global design issue.

I have service which defines some aggregates and those aggregates publish events. Let's pick one aggregate from the service and call it A.
Now, im defining another service which has some aggregate that is supposed to work with the A, lets call the second aggregate B.

When A publishes some event i want to send command to the B (ideally through saga) but im having a hard time calculating appropriate id of B (the A does not know that B exists, therefore the events it publishes does not have any hint on how to calculate the id)

I can think of few possible scenarios:

First one would be statically calculating the ID of B based on the id of A, for example in axon i could do something like `some-id-${suffix}` so when i receive event from A with `some-id` i can immediately know that it should be dispatched to `some-id-B`

Second one would be using the read side? (im not sure how its properly called) and query the thing and try to find B id based on the A id but that seems a little bit of overkill.

Is there anything i could read that would navigate me through possible scenarios and give me a hint how to handle them? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to answer without the context. What is the relation between A and B exactly in the context of your application? You said that A does not know B. Does B knows A? 
Maybe A and B should be merged?

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that asking such questions is quite hard without specific context. Let's assume the context is games. You have the User aggregate which is basically maintained in different microservice, now you want to create players that are linked to this specific user. I can manage the creation just fine, but im not sure how to handle behavior on the player when some event is published by the user microservice. For example i want to disable the player when the user was disabled etc. I think it has to do with something regarding context mapping? I'm not sure

Comment: If there is one player for one user, you could use the same id for both.
If there are several players for one user, you could have a reference of your user in the player aggregate. Thus, when the user BC publishes the event about the disabling of the user with the user id, you have the information you need in the player BC to identify the player from the user id and then disable it.

Comment: Hmm thats interesting, so i could have the same ids for different type of aggregates, that solves one to many relationship. Hmm how would the identify process be like for one to many relationship then? user publishes disabled event for id xxx and this id has 5 players associated with it? In that scenario i would treat the player as an entity? So i would have User' aggregate with player entities in my player BC?

Comment: Well, what I was suggesting is something like that: `user.User(id: user.UserId)` in `user` BC and `player.Player(id: player.PlayerId, userId: player.UserId)` in `player` BC. In that case, you would need a context mapping between `user.UserId` and `player.UserId`. 
But your idea of having a 1 to 1 relationship between `user.User` and `player.User` where `player.User` would be an aggregate containing several `player.Player` is interesting. I believe that to answer this question you need to think in term of life cycle between `player.User` and `player.Player` (creation, deletion, etc).

Comment: Maybe it would be worth considering whether you need to have two separate BC for `player` and `user`

Comment: Well yeah for one to many relationship the DDD rules strikes in (i cannot span the consistency between multiple aggregates, so it would be required to have entites to solve it)
Atleast i'm sure now that mapping one id to another is just fine, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a relationship from aggregate B to aggregate A. These kind of relationships are normal and they occur all the time.

*Note: Since this question is very general and without a context, I may be missing something. If there is a more special case than the one described notify my about it.*

[This is a great read for aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)

*Note: Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0) from Martin Fowler before reading the rest of this answer, I strongly suggest it as it explains concepts related to events and commands in great detail.*

*Note: Because the term entity is also very important, from here on I will not use aggregate anymore, so assume that each entity (**Player**, **User**, **Game**) are root of their own aggregate and is a consistency boundary, so eventual consistency in this case by domain events will be used. I will also ignore CQRS at the moment to avoid having to talk about read side and write side. We will discuss and implement a **Model***

Let take the example with the game. You have a **Player** that should represent a **User** in a **Game**. The **Player** entity should reference the **Game** and **User** in some way. It can be via a direct reference or by ID. In the case of distributed system it will be by ID. For our example Lets use UUIDs (for example **8d670541-aa51-470b-9e72-1d9227669d0c**) for ID's so we can generate them randomly without having to define a schema, auto generate sequencial number (like in SQL databases) or a special algorithm. 
Let's say that a **User** has **UserStatistics**. So when that when a **Player** makes scores (for example by killing other players in a shooting game) the **UserStatistics** entity should be created if not exists and updated. The **UserStatistics** should reference **User** by ID also, so we have a dependency from **UserStatistics** to **User**.

**UserStatistics** will look like this:

```
UserStatistics {
  UUID UserID,
  uint KillsCount,
  uint GamesPlayedCount
}
```

Because the **Player** cannot exists without a **User**, the **User** should be created first. Because a **Player** is part of a **Game** than means that the **Game** should be created first. Let define some terminology in our **Ubiquitous Language**. A **User** ***'joins'*** a **Game** by becoming a **Player** in it. Let say that Game will be created by someone else, not **Users** to avoid having to discuss the situation when the **User** creates a game and should join it also at the same time etc. Should this happen in the same transaction etc... The **Game** will be something like a MMO where it is created by someone and regular users can join.

When a **User** *joins* a **Game**, then the **Player** entity will be created with a *userID* and *gameID*. Creating a **Player** without an **userID** and **gameID** is not valid.

Let discuss the problem with **Commands** and **Events**. **Commands** can be **Triggered** by **Events**. Let use the **Observer Pattern**. One **Entity** will have to observe another **Entity** for events. In our example this means that the dependency is from **UserStatistics** (the observer) to **User** and **Player** (the subject/message producer). The fact that a specific **Command** on a **UserStatistics** will be executed as a reaction to an **Event** raised from **Player** and **User** should not affect the **Player** or **Player** in any way. By using an **Event** to deliberately trigger a special **Command** in a passive aggressive style is not a very good strategy. **Commands** can be triggered by a **Event**, but not only one specific **Command** can be **Triggered**. Many different **Commands** can be triggered and only the dependent **Entities**, **Services** or **Systems** should care about what happens. The **Player** and **User** just provide **Events**.

When a **User** joins a **Game** and the **Player** is created it will reference both entities by ID, so it will look something like this:

```
Player {
  UUID GameID,
  UUID UserID
}
```

Also **UserJoinedGameEvent** event will be raised from **User** entity (it cam be raised from **Game** but we will choose **User**). It looks like this:

```
UserJoinedGameEvent {
  UUID GameID,
  UUID UserID,
  UUID PlayerID
}
```

The **UserStatisticsService** can subscribe for events and update statistics.

When a **User** joins a **Game**, a process of gathering statistics will start and we will update (or create if it doesn't exists) his **UserStatistics** with how many games the he has played. At the same time when a **Player** makes a kill we will have to update the statistics again.

**StartGatheringUserStatisticsCommand** will be triggered from **UserJoinedGameEvent** event.

Let's add an event **PlayerMadeKillEvent** that looks like this:

```
PlayerMadeKillEvent {
 UUID UserID,
 UUID PlayerID,
 UUID GameID
}
```

**UserStatisticsService** will subscribe for **PlayerMadeKillEvents** and update **UserStatistics** by using **PlayerMadeKillEvent.UserID** to find the statistics for the specific **User**.

When a **User** quits a **Game**, a **UserQuitsGameEvent** can be raised and statistics gathering can stop.

In this example we didn't have a specific schema to generate special ID's, we can reference other aggregates that will be created first and then use their ID.

Comment: That is great context mapping example. Thanks! 
So basically what you're saying is that i should 'transfer' these references through events instead linking them statically?( ex player has unique id but when events are published and observers of those events require the user id of that player i should pass it through an event)

Comment: Your welcome, glad you liked it :) Yes exactly. Add data to events and use them for notifications of what happened. This data can be used from subscribers. This creates a loose coupling and you can easy add new 
aggregates and services, by subscribing to events. In the video, Martin Fowler calls this pattern Event Carried State Transfer. You can add as much data as you need so you don't have to make additional calls back to the event publisher (be careful, you don't to have an event with 100 properties :) If something like this happens consider breaking them down to multiple events )

Comment: In the other link, Vaughn Vernon describes the Reference By ID method and how it allows you to couple more loosely aggregates. You can also search for additional information on referencing aggregates from multiple bounded context. This paper http://adrianmarriott.net/logosroot/papers/LifeBeyondTxns.pdf from Path Helland is also a great read. It's not about DDD, but has great similarities to it by defining Entities and Activities between them:

Comment: You are my savior <3

Comment: Hmm just a question regarding the event delivery things, afik i should consider at least once delivery which means that the event might be processed twice, assuming such would it be necessary to calculate new player id based on what's in the received event (eg user id)? so that the creation of new player is idempotent?

Comment: A yes, the event delivery :) This one is interesting. You may need idempotency. The specific case will affect the solution. Uniqueness comes into play here. A player must be unique for a User for a specific Game. A User may be able to join multiple Games. You can randomly generate the player ID by using UUID, but have a logic that checks if a player with this UserID and GameID doesn't exists already. You can also choose not to use a UUID and instead use the combination of UserID and GameID as a PlayerID. The player gets destroyed after the user quits, so having a UUID may not bring any value.